# How can I create database in SQL inside PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I already create a database in MySQL using

```
CREATE DATABASE register
```

And I set

```
$db= "CREATE DATABASE register";

$host="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname= "register";


//create database connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
```

but some error that becomes error

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'register' in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\html\reg.php on line 19

How can I fix that

Comment: Probably because your `$db` is just a string; there's no database action involved so the database `register` is never created. Als I would argue agains creating a database in such a script, as it would ree-create a database every time this script is called.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a database or trying to make a new one?

Comment: tring to make new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify a database:

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
```

You can then issue your query with `$conn->real_query($db)` (which is OK because you're just issuing a statement without any user data) and use `$conn->select_db` to make the database the active db after creating it.

Your assignment in the beginning (`$db = ...`) doesn't do anything else than assign the value to a variable - the query isn't ran before you actually send it to MySQL.